# What is the right way to zoom the camera out from a scene view?

Tags: coronasdk

I have a scene where my gameplay happens. I'm looking for a way to slowly 'zoom-out' so more and more space becomes visible as the time passes. But I want the HUD and some other elements to stay the same size. It's like the mouse wheel functionality in top-down games.

I tried to do it with sticking everything into display groups and transitioning the xScale, yScale. It works visually of course but game functionality screws up. For example I have a spawner that spawns some objects, its graphics gets scaled but spawner still spawns the objects from its original position, not the new scaled position..

Do I need to keep track of every X, Y position I'm using during gameplay and transition them too? (Which is probably possible but too hard for me since I use a lot of touch events for aiming and path creating etc.) Or is there an easier way to achieve this? Please please say yes :P

I'm looking forward for your answers, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm coming from GameSalad and they had **camera.width** and **camera.height** and you simply changed them. For example from 320x480 to 640x960 to make everything smaller.

 

If Corona has something like this, I can use it and change the size of the HUD elements accordingly to compensate.

 

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are scaling your image, but not your position coordinates. 
You need to convert from 'original coordinates' to 'scaled coordinates'

If you scale your map size to half, you should scale the move amounts by half too.
You need to 'scale' your coordinates in the same amount your image is scaled.

For example lets assume your scale factor is 0.5, you have an image:

```
local scaleFactor = 0.5
image.xScale = scaleFactor
image.yScale = scaleFactor
```

Then you would need to scale your move amounts by this factor

```
thingThatIsMoved.x = thingThatIsMoved.x + (moveAmount * scaleFactor)
thingThatIsMoved.y = thingThatIsMoved.y + (moveAmount * scaleFactor)
```

I hope this helps, I am assuming you have a moveAmount variable and updating the position on the enterFrame() event.